# Salesforce SSO with multiple identity providers

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, adfs

Is it possible to configure multiple ADFS and Azure AD on a single Salesforce org for enabling SSO with multiple identity providers

Comment: What's your use case? why do have multiple identity providers?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can configure multiple Identity Providers in the same Org and let Users choose which IdP to use when they login. There is no restriction to be able to configure multiple IdPs in an Org.

I have had a similar use case where Users were located in different continents and the IdP was specific to a particular continent. So we went ahead and configured two IdPs and allowed Users to choose which one they wanted to use on the login page.

Comment: Agree with @Jayant, when setup multiple IdP in Salesforce (whether SAML or an Authentication Provider), you can control which IdP links show up on the the users login via My Domain configuration